# Leakage current in supercapacitors stack

Tags: supercapacitor, leakage-current

Given a circuit of four hybrid supercapacitors in series, connected in parallel with another branch of supercaps in series (4s, 2p), where the leakage current is illustrated as a parallel resistance on each capacitor (the capacitor's datasheet states 25uA at 3.7V, so I calculated the resistance).

**How is the total leakage current of the supercapacitor stack calculated?**

Each supercapacitor in series is also connected in parallel with the one in series of the other branch (e.g. C1 in parallel with C5), because the controller must do the balancing in the points A, B, C, D. Anyway, I need to know also what happens when the controller is disconnected.

Datasheets:

[Supercapacitors](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/87/Eaton_supercapacitor-hybrid-cylindrical-cells-data-1847238.pdf)

[Controller](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc3350.pdf)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faXcBr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: *"the capacitor's datasheet states 25uA at 3.7V"*, which would lead to 148 kOhm right? Please add links to the datashets (capacitor and controller).

Comment: Recalculate the resistances!

Comment: @devnull thanks
https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/87/Eaton_supercapacitor-hybrid-cylindrical-cells-data-1847238.pdf
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc3350.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the resistances. Distraction error.

Comment: The leakage current is independent from the stack height, 50 µA expected maximum.

Comment: @Jens may you please explain why? Best.

Comment: @Nic1337 If I look e.g. at stack segment C, there is the leakage current inside C3 and C7, 25 µA each, 50 µA in total. There is no current path to parts of other segments, it is an island. So the whole stack behaves like one segment does.

Answer (score 0):

> How is the total leakage current of the supercapacitor stack calculated?

> I need to know also what happens when the controller is disconnected.

Each supercapacitor will discharge according to its own leakage current. If you take the equivalent capacitance (using the small value in the question, just as an example), the "total leakage" will be twice the individual value, due to the parallel association:

[image]

Notice that the voltage in the stack association is divided by 4 in the graph.

> may you please explain why?

Each two parallel capacitors have twice the leakage current, so the following equivalent circuit presents the same discharge characteristics:

[image]

Comment: In the equivalent circuit with the parallel, you calculated C2 as 0.5 uF for the four capacitors in series. Why? The capacitance in series should be divided: so, 1uF / 4 = 0.25uF

Comment: "In the equivalent circuit with the parallel, you calculated C2 as 0.5 uF for the four capacitors in series." No. It is the equivalent circuit for the 8 capacitors. Also notice the doubled leakage current. *"If you take the equivalent capacitance [...], the "total leakage" will be twice the individual value, due to the **parallel** association:"*